# Is $L_4$ a CFL?

Tags: formal-languages, automata, context-free-grammar, formal-grammar, pumping-lemma

> Consider the following language: $$L_4 = \{a^ib^jc^kd^l : i,j,k,l
>     \ge0 \wedge i=1 \Rightarrow j=k=l\}.$$
>    Prove or disprove: $L_4$ is a context-free language.

To me, it looks like $L_4$ can be accepted using a PDA, but I don't know how to construct it.
appreciate a hint here.

Comment: The sub-language for $i=1$ is not context.free

Comment: Can you give me a hint of how to disprove it then?

Comment: The pumping lemma for context-free languages would do it.

Comment: is $w = ab^kc^kd^k$ a good choice? for $k$ being the constant from the pumping lemma.

Comment: More precisely, what the pumping lemma shows _directly_ is @Wuestenfux's claim. To get all the way to $L_4$, note that "the sub-language for $i=1$" is the intersection of $L_4$ and a regular language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the context-free languages are closed under intersection with a regular language and under homomorphism, if $L_4$ were context-free then so would the following language be, for the homomorphism given by $h(a) = \epsilon$ and $h(\sigma) = \sigma$ for $\sigma \neq a$:
$$
h(L_4 \cap a(b+c+d)^*) = \{ b^nc^nd^n : n \geq 0 \}.
$$
However, the latter language is well-known not to be context-free.